# How to replace empty spaces with values from adjacent colum that needs to be separated?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

> Hi everyone. I'm so sorry for my english. I need to separate the
> domain data of some emails in a table. Then, if these mail data have
> the domain of a country, this information must be moved to another
> column that is incomplete in which the participants of a congress are
> included. This for a relatively large database. I put an example
> below.
>
> ```
> | email                         | country        | 
> | --------                      | -------------- | 
> | naco@gmail.com                | CO             |
> | monic45814@gmail.com          | AR             |
> | jsalazar@chapingo.mx          |                | 
> | andresramirez@urosario.edu.co |                |
> | jeimy861491@hotmail.com       | CL             |
> |jytvc@hotmail.com              |                |
>
> Outcome should be
>
> | email                         | country        | 
> | --------                      | -------------- | 
> | naco@gmail.com                | CO             |
> | monic45814@gmail.com          | AR             |
> | jsalazar@chapingo.mx          | MX             | 
> | andresramirez@urosario.edu.co | CO             |
> |jeimy861491@hotmail.com        | CL             |
> |jytvc@hotmail.com              | *NA*           |
> ```
>
> Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution in base R.

Suppose:

```
df<-data.frame(email,country)
```

Then:

```
df$country<-ifelse(is.na(df$country)&sub(".*(.*?)[\\.|:]", "",df$email)!="com",sub(".*(.*?)[\\.|:]", "",df$email),paste(df$country))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str_extract` to get the string after the last occurrence of "." and `if_else` to ignore rows that already have a country and rows which e-mail doesn't end with a country code:

```
df %>%
  mutate(country = if_else(is.na(country) & str_extract(email, "[^.]+$") != "com", toupper(str_extract(email, "[^.]+$")), country))
```

small but not so small PS: I would always recommend to provide fake data when you are mentioning personal data like e-mail addresses

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and for the advice. I had already changed the names of the emails before posting. I just let the domains as the original.